# Lightweight way of flooring an NSDecimal?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have an NSDecimal in a tight calculations loop, where I need to floor the value. I want to prevent creating fat NSDecimalNumber objects just for that. Is there a cost-efficient way to get a floor? That floor is just needed to calculate how many times another value might fit in there, with no rest. The NSDecimal API doesn't provide something like floor...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `NSDecimalRound()` function with the `NSRoundDown` rounding mode:

```
NSDecimal d = ...;
NSDecimal floored;

NSDecimalRound(&floored, &d, 0, NSRoundDown);
```

For more info take a look at the docs [here](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSDecimalRound).

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDecimal result;
NSDecimalRound(&result, &decimal, 0, NSRoundDown);
```

(not tested)